# RISC-V jumps with zero offset

Tags: assembly, riscv

I want to verify my understanding of the RISC-V standard concerning jump commands.

For this, I have considered the three following three assembly commands:

```
j 0
j 4
j 8
```

where `j` is the jump pseudo-instruction; `j o := jal x0 o`

It is my understanding that

- `j 0` jumps to the current pc, which is the `j 0` command again thus creating an infinite loop
- `j 4` jumps to pc + 4 which basically is a fancy noop (ignoring the quality of the noop because of branch prediction shenanigans and other stuff going on in the CPU)
- `j 8` jumps to pc + 8, effectively skipping the next instruction.

Is this intuition correct? Something that seems odd to me is how 'easy' it is to create an infinite dummy loop with `j 0`. But on the other hand this is likely not an issue because no compiler would generate such a statement, correct?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: "It's suspiciously easy to encode something stupid" - you might enjoy reading up on [HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire_(computing)).

Comment: Interesting, `clang -target riscv32 -c foo.s` does indeed assemble multiple `j 0` to `01 a0` jump to itself, so it's assembling the numeric operand straight into the relative offset in the machine code.  vs. many assemblers (like GAS for x86) treating numbers as absolute target addresses.  Anyway, yes, you're correct if your RISC-V doesn't use RV32c compressed (16-bit) instructions so every instruction is 4 bytes wide.

Comment: *Something that seems odd to me is how 'easy' it is to create an infinite dummy loop with j 0* - why would you not want to have an encoding for a jump to itself?  `foo: j foo` is something that you might find in an idle task in a toy OS that hasn't yet implemented power-saving, or just in a busy loop in user-space as a 'make load' experiment.  (interrupts can still interrupt it.)  *No compiler would generate it* - it's how you compile `while(1){}`, which is legal in C (not modern C++ without a volatile side-effect.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, I did not consider interrupts and that one would actually want 'dumb' jumps. Thanks for that clarification!

Comment: "*Something that seems odd to me is how 'easy' it is to...*"  It takes more work for the hardware to exclude useless and redundant encodings than to simply allow them.  So, for example, while there is one official `nop` encoding, there's many, many was to do `nop` — most targeting `x0` with some result.  There's multiple ways to double a value (e.g. by add, by shift), etc..  Ultimately, it is up to software to use the instruction set to get a meaningful/intended result.